# use network drive in task scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, windows-task-scheduler, network-drive

I have a python programm which has a path to a network drive, when I run this programm with cmd, i get the error that cmd can not find the path. I should run the programm from windows task scheduler, What is the solution?

```
EXPORT_PATH = 'Z:\DB-Maintenance\dump\\' + CLIENT
```

Comment: Use full UNC path `\\Server\Share` rather than drive letter `Z:`, since the latter is not available unless the scheduled task runs under your user context…

Comment: I did that, but instead of using this path, it makes a path like this in loacal computer and continues.

Comment: Please read in Python documentation the section about [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) to get knowledge about the different possibilities which exist to define a string in Python containing backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is : define the path like : `\\\\server\share`

it needs 4 backslashes.

Comment: A string needs all REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) characters escaped. `\\\\SERVERNAME\\SHARENAME`. Alternatively, a "raw" string can be used. `r'\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME'`.